# Running function of variable name

Tags: function, powershell

I expected this code to run `Foo()`:

```
function Foo {
    [Console]::WriteLine("Foo")
}
$Bar = [Console]::ReadLine()
# If $Bar is Foo then it should do the function "Foo", right?

$Bar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions in powershell follow a `verb-noun` pattern and most .NET methods have a powershell equivalent known as`cmdlet` so your function can be :

```
function Get-Foo {
    #[Console]::WriteLine('Foo')
    Write-Host 'This is foo'
}

Get-Foo
```

or

```
$Bar = Get-Foo

$Bar
```

`Get-Command` and `Get-Help` are your friends, try them out.

Comment: Doesn't exactly do what I want it to, I think that's my fault for making it too broad, I fixed it to be what I actually want to do.

Comment: you feed $bar with user input from `[console]::readline() which will always be a string.... foo `function` and foo `string` are not the same thing